# JavaScript and Cloud code function, share the same var

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, webstorm

I use `parse.com`as backend service for my `iOS`app. I was trying to do everything in `objective-c` since I don't have any experience with `JavaScript`, but turns out I will need to develop some `Cloud Code Functions` in `JavaScript` to complete my `app`.

A simple routine I'm trying to create:

1. User retrieves an object using a `Cloud Function`.
2. User saves another object in a different class.
3. An `afterSave`function runs in the cloud to update object first retrieved.

Now, here is my code:

```
var UserConfigOrientador = Parse.Object.extend("UserConfigOrientador");
var query = new Parse.Query(UserConfigOrientador);

Parse.Cloud.define('pegarOrientadorLivre', function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    query.greaterThan("entrevistasDisponibilidade", 0);
    query.first({
       success: function(results) {
            response.success(results);
            query = results;
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error('Favor, checar rede e tentar novamente.');
        }
    });
});

// AfterSave
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Agenda", function(request) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    query.set("entrevistasDisponibilidade", 70);
    query.save();
        }
    });
});
```

Now, the second function is not working, I'm getting the message that Object has no `set` method.

Basically, my questions are:

How can I share data between functions?
Should I keep everything in `main.js` or can I use another file?

I'm using `webStorm` for development. And the question about `main.js` is that after a while I will have a lot of functions and I am trying to figure out how to organize my code.

Comment: If you verify `new Parse.Query(UserConfigOrientador).set` it is defined there? All those codes you had show is in the same file?

Comment: Yes, codes are in the same file. I'm not sure how to check if it is defined. Thanks.

Comment: When I try to alert the object `alert (JSON.stringify(query));` in the `afterSave`function, it doesn't show the object that supposed to be in the global variable. I don't understand it. When I log it from the first function, it shows that the object is correctly assigned to the variable, for some reason, it is not being retained. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried rename to something more unique? like var4455424. Just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is one of scope, and poorly named variables that you're reusing for multiple purposes.

You define your `query` variable as a query, use it, but inside the `success` handler you set it to the result of the query (you now have a variable called `query` which is actually an instance of your `UserConfigOrientador` class).

When that Cloud Code finishes running, the result goes out of scope and is most likely set to `undefined`. You shouldn't be trying to share variables between multiple Cloud Code methods like that.

Is there something on the `Agenda` object that can let you know which `UserConfigOrientador` to update? Perhaps you could add a pointer property to the `UserConfigOrientador`? If you did, then you could use the following:

```
// AfterSave
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Agenda", function(request) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var userConfigOrientadorQuery = new Parse.Query("UserConfigOrientador");
    // read "userConfigOrientador" pointer property on "Agenda" object
    var userConfigId = request.object.get("userConfigOrientador").id;
    userConfigOrientadorQuery.get(userConfigId, {
        success: function(userConfigOrientador) {
            userConfigOrientador.set("entrevistasDisponibilidade", 70);
            userConfigOrientador.save();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mm.. I don't think it quite works the way you expect.

When your Cloud code runs, your initial `var query` declaration is indeed available within the scope of your cloud function and afterSave function. However, you're not passing it in correctly. As a matter of fact, I'm a little confused because your query seems to be requesting a `UserConfigOrientador` object while your `afterSave` is on an `Agenda` object.

So there are two different things going on here. Since you don't actually save an agenda object, I'm assuming that your `response.success()` returns a JSON of the `UserConfigOrientador` object back to client side at which point you do some manipulation then save the `Agenda` object based on that result.

At this point, when you `save()` the `Agenda` object now the `afterSave()` function will run but your query value will be the `var query = new Parse.Query(UserConfigOrientador);` which does not have a set method. This is why you get the error.

I'm not even sure your `query = results;` line will actually execute as you should be calling it at the END of your sub-routine and it signals to Parse that it is the end.

If you can tell me how you're saving the `Agenda` object I can probably complete the picture.

**EDIT: ---** abstracted but maybe this is the pattern you're looking for...

```
var ObjectA = Parse.Object.extend('ObjectA');
var queryObjectA = new Parse.Query('ObjectA');

Parse.Cloud.define('findObjectX', function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
// other query options here...
query.first({
   // the first() function will return a Parse.Object
   success: function(objectX) {
       // Now you have objectX
       // Now you want to save some other object
       var otherObj = new ObjectA();
       // Do things to otherObj
       otherObj.save({
           success: function(result) { // will be the saved otherObj
               // Now you do stuff to your queried obj and save
               objectX.set('something', result); // or whatever
               // Note, it accomplishes what I think you want without afterSave()
           }
       }); // async... but we can just let this guy go

   },
   error: function(error) {
       response.error('Favor, checar rede e tentar novamente.');
   }
});
});
```